# How do I permanently disable / prevent auto-rotation?

Tags: windows-10

I want to make it so that my tablet computer will NEVER rotate.
I have switched "Rotation Lock" to "ON".

[image]

But as soon as I detach the keyboard, "Rotation Lock" becomes enabled again and automatically set to "OFF".

[image]

I want to prevent this. The screen should never rotate.

However, this seems to be really difficult to accomplish.

I have added the following registry entries, but it wouldn't help.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation]
"Enable"=dword:00000000
"LastOrientation"=dword:00000000
"SlateEnable"=dword:00000001
"SensorPresent"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation\NonPreserve]
"LastAutoRequest"=dword:00000000
```

Does anybody have any more ideas what I could do?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the key change when it does "its thing" or is more like the key is not used?

Comment: Workaround: Set  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation`, `Enable` =0, and save that as a .reg file, However, after reapplying that .reg file, you'll need to log out and then log in again for it to take effect. sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem with my Asus Zenbook Flip 14.

You need to find out the driver responsible for detecting the orientation.
Look up what it is exactly called for your device. Then, find it in the list of devices in the **Device Manager** (Win + X → M), under the **System Devices** heading.

In my case the device was ***Intel(R) Integrated Sensor Solution***. Right-click on the device and select **Disable device** (Or click on the White, Down arrow button on the toolbar). To enable auto-rotation, simply select **Enable device**  (Or click on the Green, Up arrow button).

This image may help:
[image]

To reduce my efforts, I made this Powershell script to toggle between the two settings:

```
$sensor = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.friendlyname -like "Intel(R) Integrated Sensor Solution"}

# Write the name of your device in the double quotes

switch ($sensor.Status) {
    'OK' { 
        Disable-PnpDevice $sensor.DeviceID -Confirm:$false
        break
    }
    default {
        Enable-PnpDevice $sensor.DeviceID -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```